# Grouping separately

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/wu5hk/1/

```
<div class="coach-group">
    <div class="coach">1</div>
    <div class="coach">2</div>
    <div class="coach">3</div>
    <div class="coach">4</div>
    <div class="coach">5</div>
    <div class="coach">6</div>
    <div class="coach">7</div>
    <div class="coach">8</div>
</div>
second set
<div class="coach-group">
    <div class="coach">1</div>
    <div class="coach">2</div>
    <div class="coach">3</div>
    <div class="coach">4</div>
    <div class="coach">5</div>
    <div class="coach">6</div>
    <div class="coach">7</div>
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see in the example, I'm unable to separate the groups...selecting 7th in the first set considers the 2nd in the 2nd set to be the fifth element of the row.

How do I treat each group separately preferably without editing the markup?

Comment: I am attracted more by how you made the arrow right now. ;)

Comment: When you click on the second set after the 2, is the jumping of the last line intended behaviour?

Comment: No it isn't. I suppose its happening due to the preview pane loading before its positioning is known.

Comment: So what is the expected behaviour of the yellow bg? The fifth in line or the last? That is confusing due to the jumping. Or "last in line || fifth"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated cached `elements` variable to current `.coach-group` context

JS:

```
...
$('.coach-group').children(".coach").click(function(){
    elements = $(this).closest(".coach-group").children(".coach"); // kinda ugly but the idea is to update elements list to .coach-group context
    container.children().removeClass('selected'); // reset selected element
    $(this).addClass('selected'); // mark new selected element
...
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/NnKKc/1/

**EDIT**

Here are some updates:

added some custom styles ( essentialy - just a fixed height ) smooth out slideUp and slideDown

moved arrow pointer to be positioned via CSS ( looses IE7 compatibility -oh well ) and layout looks slightly off ( which im sure can be fixed easily )

Anyway, did some major refactoring on the JS side of things and heres the final result which does the job.

```
//possibly encapsulate this whole shenanigan in a self invoking function?

$cell = $(".coach");
$coachGroup = $(".coach-group");

var cellWidth = $cell.width();
var containerWidth = $coachGroup.width();
var cellsInRow = Math.floor( containerWidth / cellWidth );

var currentSectionIndex = -1;
var currentSelectedElementIndex = -1;
var currentEdgeElementIndex = -1;

function resetSection( $section ) {
    $section.find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $section.find(".edge").removeClass("edge");
    $section.find(".info-bg").slideUp( function() { $(this).remove(); } );
    currentSelectedElementIndex = -1;
    currentEdgeElementIndex = -1;
}

function getEdgeElementIndexFrom( currentIndex ) {
    var rowNumber = Math.floor( currentIndex / cellsInRow ) + 1;
    var lastElementIndex = rowNumber * cellsInRow;
    return lastElementIndex;
}

function handleClick( $cell, $activeSection ) {
    var selectedElementIndex = $cell.index();
    var $allCells = $activeSection.children();

    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $cell.addClass("selected");

    var edgeElementIndex = getEdgeElementIndexFrom( selectedElementIndex );
    var totalElements = $activeSection.children().length;

    if ( edgeElementIndex > totalElements ) {
        edgeElementIndex = totalElements;
    }

    edgeElementIndex = edgeElementIndex - 1;

    if ( edgeElementIndex == currentEdgeElementIndex ) {
        console.log( selectedElementIndex );
        console.log( currentSelectedElementIndex );
        if ( selectedElementIndex == currentSelectedElementIndex ) {
            var $infoBg = $(".info-bg");
            if ( $infoBg.is(":visible") ) {
                $infoBg.slideUp();
                $cell.removeClass("selected");                    
            } else {
                $infoBg.slideDown();    
                $cell.addClass("selected");
            }
        } else {
            currentSelectedElementIndex = selectedElementIndex;
            $(".info-bg").slideDown();
        }

    } else {
        currentEdgeElementIndex = edgeElementIndex;
        var $edgeCell = $allCells.eq( currentEdgeElementIndex ); 

        $allCells.find(".edge").removeClass("edge");
        $edgeCell.addClass("edge");

        $(".info-bg").slideUp( function() { $(this).remove(); } );

        var $info = $(".info-template").clone();
        $info.removeClass("info-template").addClass("info-bg");

        $edgeCell.after( $info );

        $info.slideDown();
    }
}

$cell.on("click", function() {
    var $this = $( this );
    var $activeSection = $this.closest( ".coach-group" );
    var activeSectionIndex = $activeSection.index();

    if ( currentSectionIndex != activeSectionIndex  ) {
        var $oldSection = $coachGroup.eq( currentSectionIndex );
        resetSection( $oldSection );

        currentSectionIndex = activeSectionIndex;
    }

    handleClick( $this, $activeSection );
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/65QQ3/6/

Comment: Go from the first set to the second set and you will have two arrows, clicking I mean.

Comment: Hmm..almost works, but check http://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/NnKKc/3/ it doesn't recognize the rows correctly

Comment: Wonderful!! If you weren't a man, I'd say love you! ;) Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

```
<div class="coach-group group1">
            items...    
    </div>

    <div class="coach-group group2">
            items...
    </div>
```

**Option 2:**

```
var first = $(".coach-group")[0];
var second = $(".coach-group")[1];
```

Comment: Still, I have to manually target each group, there might be many. An automated solution would be ideal.